# Improved var_dump function with more detailed and styled

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to understand data styles. I check variables buy using var_dump and pring_r. These are working good but I struggle when to use which of it. And they just print text current position. I use this functions for development and it can be more stylish. Is there any function covers both function and returns result in better look.

Comment: Try using https://xdebug.org/ 

It's a PHP extension for better debugging.

Comment: I will try. Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

you can try add some html like:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Your array output will be way more "styled" and easy to read.

Comment: That code should throw a syntax error. Also, how is this "styled"?

Comment: I forgot the double quotes, fixed that. It is styled because of the html tag pre which is used from the browser.  It preformats all the output and makes the array way more readable.

Answer (score 0):

When I was using laravel framework there was a function called `dd` and it was suit for using all type of data. I tried to copy it in php way and created a function.

See below

```php
function dd($var){
  echo '<pre style="font-size:14px;">';
  if (is_array($var) || is_object($var)) {
    echo htmlentities(print_r($var, true));
  } elseif (is_string($var)) {
    echo "string(" . strlen($var) . ") \"" . htmlentities($var) . "\"\n";
  } else {
    var_dump($var);
  }
  echo "\n</pre>";
}
```